# Django abstract class, form page on select dynamically

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

If i'm creating i.e. an item in `/admin/product/` i get some 2 fields that are described in product/models.py class `Item`: `category` and `name`;
 I would like a 3rd field appear dynamically while creating an item depending on chosen category(`a` or `b`):

```
CATEGORIES = (
          ('a', 'Apple'),
          ('b', 'Banana'),
)

class Item(models.Model):
    category    = models.ForeignKey(choices=CATEGORIES)

    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
"""
category.a:
    color       = models.CharField(max_length=21)
category.b:
    count       = models.CharField(max_length=21)
"""
```

The field `name` will be as for `a` so for `b` categories and (`color` or `count`) field will appear only for (`a` or `b`) categories respectively;


Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.


**P.S.**

 Sorry for someway incorrect title;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is have models that change based on the category.
The way I would do this is to define an abstract model (probably called fruit, in this case) with all the common information, and then inherit from it in a model called bananas and a model called apples.

To add a new banana/apple, then, I would use either the appropriate admin form or add logic to the appropriate view that determines which sort of object to add.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Edit: Unfortunately I don't know how the admin interface deals with abstract classes, and I don't have a test install to hand. As for the logic, in the view I would expect the logic to be something like:

```
from models import banana, apple
def fruitView(request)
     if request.REQUEST["Type"] = "Banana":
          b = banana(request.REQUEST["Count"])
          b.save()
     else:
          a = apple(request.REQUEST["Colour"])
          a.save()
```

Comment: Abstract class seems to fit nice. Could you give a small example about the last paragraph? Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with views, but I think that edit should give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Voted up bad still cannot get it work as expected: parameters(count,color) don't change when selecting category(banana, apple). Ajax needed?

Comment: Ahh, you want to do this dynamically on display of the website. Yes,  ajax will be needed - officially passing you outside of my expertise. Sorry.

Comment: OK, consider ajax to be another question, still your answer helped, thank you (: